# How to set a directory for multiple C file in GCC

Tags: c, gcc

Suppose I have some `.c` files name `aa.c`, `bb.c` with their header files respectively in a folder called `lib` and main file `main.c` in root directory. Here's the structure:

```
root
 -- main.c
 -- lib
    -- aa.c
    -- bb.c
    -- aa.h
    -- bb.h
```

Now, how can I compile all C files present in `lib` folder without giving relative path full time. That is, instead of doing this:

```
cc main.c lib/aa.c lib/bb.c
```

How can I do to set directory only one time and compile all files of it? I know, I can do it by creating object files or static library, but can it be possible to directly compile C files.

I tried using `-I` or `-L` option for `.c` extension but it doesn't work (it works only for library files or object files).

Comment: Create a Makefile for your project could be the easiest way.

Comment: Yes makefile is the easiest way, but I want to know is there's an option for this.

Comment: I believe there is no such option. If you really want it, you can create a shell script wrapper of your compiler to do it.

Comment: Waiting for more answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all source files in `lib` and you are use a shell with filename expansion, you could try something like

```
cc -I./lib main.c lib/*.c
```

Comment: What if I want only restricted set of C files of lib? Is there's a native option like for library files `-L`, object files `-I`.

Comment: @ashish2expert So you only need to list the file names instead of relative paths? If this is what you want, then I believe a wrapper script of your compiler is the best solution. However, I prefer Makefile solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler where to search for headers:

```
cc -I./lib main.c lib/aa.c lib/bb.c
```

Comment: No, instead of including `lib` directory multiple times, can I do it by including only one time.

Comment: @ashish2expert Does `cc -I./lib main.c lib/*.c` work?

Comment: @ashish2expert try `make VPATH=lib main.o aa.o bb.o`

Comment: That's better. `cc -I./lib main.c lib/*.c`